# Incorporate a delete button with alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have am writing a code where I can edit or delete certain details from the database.
Right now, if the user clicks on the edit button it takes him edit page where he can edit the details.
But, I am not able to Incorporate a Delete button such that, when the user clicks on a delete button,
it should ask for a confirmation box. If the user clicks YES, then do the following:

```
DELETE from emp WHERE emp_id='$emp_id';
```

Here is my code so far

```
while($get_emp = mysql_fetch_assoc($emp_query)){
    $emp_id = $get_emp['emp_id'];
    $emp_name = $get_emp['first_name']." ".$get_emp['last_name'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='100'>";
    echo $emp_id;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='300'>";
    echo $emp_name;
    $edit_path = 'edit_employee.php?id='.$emp_id;

    ?>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" value="EDIT" onClick="location.href='<?php echo $edit_path; ?>'"> 
    <?
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

ok so i tried the following code and it works...but after it deletes the row, it doesnt seem to refresh the page. I mean the entry is still visible in the page. I need to refresh the page to clear it out..

```
        <form style='margin: 0; padding: 0;' style='display:inline;' method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure this is correct?');">
            <input style='display:inline;' name="delbutton" type="submit" value="DELETE">
            <?php if(!empty($_POST['delbutton'])){
                    $del_emp = mysql_query("DELETE from employee WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'") or die(mysql_error());
            header('Location:page.php');
                  }
        echo '</form>';
```

ok as per kevin's suggestion I added the header part.

I have one more issue to deal with.. When there are multiple entries and I click on delete it deletes everything from the database. How can I make it to delete only the entry that is besides the delete button?

Comment: you can use confirm. if(confirm("Delete")){...}

Comment: use header("location: yourpage.php"); once you done with your sql query ( answer to the edited question )

Comment: thanks @kevin ..now it refreshes the page..but i have one more issue to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like ...

```
if (confirm('Are you sure?') {
    deleteRecord(...);
    location.href=location.href; // force a page refresh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jQuery to add a click event handler on your delete button. Unforunately both do not have native support for a confirmation dialog, but there are literally hundreds of ready scripts on the web. From a simple google search i ended up with [this](http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/), but you can search for one that suits your purposes.